# Programming exercise: Writing a story in python

Tags: python

I tried to use this code:

```py
name= input("Please type in a name")
year= input("Please type in a year")
print(name + " " + "is a valiant knight, born in the year") 
print(year + ".One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Mary could save the village's residents.")
```

Output:

```
Mary is a valiant knight, born in the year
1572.One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Mary could save the village's residents.
```

Expected output:

```
Mary is a valiant knight, born in the year 1340. One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Jeremy could save the village's residents.
```

Comment: add the jermy in the print statement and provide the expected year

Comment: First I recommend you learn about so-called [*f-strings*](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Then print using a *single* `print` call.

Comment: Hint:  In Python, `print` outputs a line.  You want the year to be printed on the first line.  So it needs to be in the first print statement

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - f-strings are maybe a bit advanced for beginners doing "first steps" exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you call the function `print` you break the line in the end. But, you can use the `end` parameter to change this:

```py
print(name + " " + "is a valiant knight, born in the year", end=" ") 
print(year + ".One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Mary could save the village's residents.")
```

Note that, if you dont specify the `end` parameter it means that you are doning `end="\n"`.

But, for a **better solution** I recommend that you format the output:

```py
print(f"{name} is a valiant knight, born in the year {year}. One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Mary could save the village's residents.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the entire text to appear as one string.

```
# One solution is to end your print statements with a space rather than a line break, which happens by default
print(name + " " + "is a valiant knight, born in the year", end = ' ') 
print(year + ".One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Mary could save the village's residents.", end = ' ')
```

Another solution is to just create your story as a single line of text

```
story = f"{name} is a valiant knight, born in the year {year}. One morning Mary woke up to an awful racket: a dragon was approaching the village. Only Mary could save the village's residents. "
print(story)
```

Comment: However the names in the story work out, you can substitute the variables around in your story.